# Workaround a bug in Samsung camera drivers

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm writing an application with a custom camera functionality. In it the picture taken from the device's camera is immediately shown to user with the question if it really needs to be saved. I'm using method:

```
public final void takePicture (Camera.ShutterCallback shutter, Camera.PictureCallback raw, Camera.PictureCallback postview, Camera.PictureCallback jpeg)
```

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29)

According to the documentation this method pauses the preview immediately after the picture has been taken, which is exactly the feature I need. However, on Samsung devices the preview is not paused, which I assume is a bug in their camera drivers. I can reproduce the bug on Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300), and QA says they reproduce it on other Samsung devices too. On devices from other manufacturers this method works just as expected.

I tried manually pausing the preview in each of the `Camera.takePicture()` callbacks, but none of them is executed at precise time when the picture is taken. This leads to a noticable difference between the picture that user is asked to review and the picture that was actually taken, which is especially terrible when the picture was taken with flashlight enabled.

Is there any way to workaround this behaviour?

Comment: As the documentation stated, not all hardware support this feature. In order to help you, I should ask, can you post the "nearby" code from the takePicture, and the manifest with the camera permissions? This is mostly to rule out any inconsistency, while cheking what scenario your application is doing. And, to go far-fetched here, is `startPreview()` working as expected?

Comment: Here's the code:`/*Saving orientation and GPS data to camera parameters*/ mCamera.setParameters(parameters); mCaptureState = CAPTURING; mCamera.takePicture(mShutterCallback, mNoOpPictureCallback, mNoOpPictureCallback, mPictureCallback);`. Both `mShutterCallback` and `mNoOpPictureCallback` are empty.

And in the manifest only `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>` is requested.

`startPreview()` and other methods work fine, except that camera preview isn't stopped by `takePicture()`.

Comment: Please, edit your question, and add the text there. These comments are harder to read. As far as I can help, you could debug the code on the device, and check what asyncronous "task" is continuing when it should be stopped. Since its a "brand" specific issue, you could disable that device for the time being. (I cant think of a bypass for now)